# Why does this block of code use both setDaemon() and join()?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-crawler

I am learning crawler with threading.The code below is to get proxies url from the list `PROXY_SITE`. The method, `save_proxies`, will request the webs providing proxy urls and insert them into MongoDB.

```
def use_thread():
    cleanup()
    threads = []
    for url in PROXY_SITES:
        t = threading.Thread(target=save_proxies, args=(url,))
        t.setDaemon(True)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

I don't understand why using the `setDaemon()` and `join()` at the same time. If the code is valid, the main thread would kill the sub-threads or await the sub-threads processed?

Comment: Since the threads are set to be 'daemons' (well, to run in such mode) without waiting for them to finish with `join()` the script will whizz through the rest and, potentially, kill them before they finish executing as 'daemon' threads are closed when the main thread exits. If the threads were not set to be 'daemons' that would not be explicitly required, but that depends on the rest of the code (if there is any).

Comment: It may be so that, if one of the threads hangs up or raises an exception, the script will be able to terminate even if other threads are still running.This is needed because _by default_ any threads created and started by the main thread will prevent it from exiting if they are still running when the main thread is terminated